# closed-form function for non linear recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, closed-form

I have The following non linear recursive sequence:

$R_{n+1}=R_{n}+\frac{1}{R_n}$, where $R_1=1$.

How do I find a closed-form function for this sequence, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this has a non-recursive closed form, but it is the same as the [fractional chromatic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalChromaticNumber.html) of the of the [Mycielski graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MycielskiGraph.html). See [A073833](https://oeis.org/A073833) and [A073834](https://oeis.org/A073834) on the OEIS for the numerators and denominators of this sequence, respectively.

Answer (score -2):

May help you: I tried a Matlab program

```
clc;  

clear;  
r=[];  

r(1)=1;

N=1000;

for n=2:N

    r(n)=r(n-1)+1/r(n-1)

end;
```

Put $N$ various number, $r_{1000}=44.7569$.
It seems to be divergent...

Comment: While you are it it: investigate $r(n)-\sqrt{2n}$. No, I don't think there is a closed form, but the growth is rather regular and predictable.

Comment: It doesn’t matter if the sequence grows unbounded.